# How to find more than one highest size using reduce() JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the highest size `accSixe = acc.width * acc.height` which is  not a problem. The trick is if there is more than one highest size how would i get it - really important- using `reduce()`.  I am trying to understand the ins and outs of `reduce()` . Any one to help?

```
    const boxarts = [
    { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
    { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" },
    { width: 400, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture400.jpg" },
    { width: 500, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture500.jpg" },
    { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg" },
    { width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600-.jpg" },
    { width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600+.jpg" },
    { width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600.jpg" },
    { width: 425, height: 150, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg" }
]

        const newReduce = boxarts.reduce(function (acc, currentValue) {

            const accSixe = acc.width * acc.height
            const curSize = currentValue.width * currentValue.height

            if (accSixe > curSize) {
                return acc
            } else {
                return currentValue
            }
        }, [])


        console.log(JSON.stringify(newReduce, null, 2))
```

Comment: What do you mean "more than one highest size"?

Comment: size = width * height . in this case we have three result with the same highest size. result should be like this :

`[{ width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600-.jpg" },
    { width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600+.jpg" },
    { width: 600, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600.jpg" }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the accumulator be an object of an array and the current highest value:

```js
const boxarts=[{width:200,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"},{width:300,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"},{width:400,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture400.jpg"},{width:500,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture500.jpg"},{width:150,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600-.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600+.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600.jpg"},{width:425,height:150,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg"}]

const { arr } = boxarts.reduce(({ highest = 0, arr = [] }, boxart) => {
  const { width, height } = boxart;
  const thisSize = width * height;
  if (thisSize > highest) return { highest: thisSize, arr: [boxart] };
  if (thisSize === highest) arr.push(boxart);
  return { highest, arr };
}, {});
console.log(arr);
```

Another option would be for the accumulator be the array itself, but you'd have to extract and multiply the record width * height every iteration:

```js
const boxarts=[{width:200,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"},{width:300,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"},{width:400,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture400.jpg"},{width:500,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture500.jpg"},{width:150,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600-.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600+.jpg"},{width:600,height:200,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600.jpg"},{width:425,height:150,url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg"}]

const arr = boxarts.reduce((foundSoFar, boxart) => {
  const record = foundSoFar[0].width * foundSoFar[0].height;
  const { width, height } = boxart;
  const thisSize = width * height;
  if (thisSize > record) return [boxart]
  if (thisSize === record) foundSoFar.push(boxart);
  return foundSoFar;
}, [{ width: 0, height: 0 }]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I like both answers! I am trying to digest it. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this problem isn't well suited to using `.reduce()`. You could solve it very straightforwardly simply iterating over item and storing the current largest items in an array.

```
 let maxSize = 0;
 let biggest = [];
 boxarts.forEach(function(box) {
    if (box.width * box.height > maxSize) {
      maxSize = box.width * box.height;
      biggest = [box];
    } else if (box.width * box.height === maxSize) {
      biggest.push(box);
    }
 });
```

Super straightforward to read and reason about.

Comment: agree! but the condition was to solve it with reduce(). this is for the education purpose. I am trying to understand the ins and outs of reduce()

Comment: That's important information that you should include in the question.